# mu4e is not working with Doom Emacs; Symbol’s value as variable is void

Tags: emacs, mu, mu4e

recently I've switched to Doom Emacs from a vanilla one, and mu4e stopped working for me.
First, when I open mu4e it gives me an error:
`Symbol’s value as variable is void: mu4e--server-props`
And then I cannot see my email folders:
`command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, mu4e-search-bookmark`
Same for search:
`command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, mu4e-search`
I'm running Nixos 22.05 and Mu 1.6.10.
No idea how to deal with the issue, googling did not provide much result...
Any help appreciated

I was trying to find similar problems on Stack Overflow, Gitghub issues, or wherever, but seems nobody experiencing the same problem...setup